# React admin Content-Range header missing when it's not

Tags: react-admin

React admin is complaining because it says Content-Range header is missing, it's not any ideas? I should point out this is the first time I've used RA so might be missing something.

express api code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Total-Count, Content-Range")
  next()
});
    app.get('/quickdrop/retailer', function(req, res) {
  const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')

  const client = new Client({
      node: 'https://creds',
    })

    var allRecords = []
    client.search({
        index: 'the index',
        type: 'product',
        scroll: '10s',
        body: {
          query: {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      }, function getMoreUntilDone(error, response) {
        // collect all the records
        console.log(allRecords.length)
        response.body.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
          allRecords.push(hit);
        });
      
        if (response.body.hits.total.value !== allRecords.length) {
          // now we can call scroll over and over
          client.scroll({
            scrollId: response.body._scroll_id,
            scroll: '10s'
          }, getMoreUntilDone);
        } else {
          const response = allRecords.map((item) => {
            return {
              title: item._source.name,
              image: item._source.tthsImage,
              barcode: item._id
            }
          })
          res.set("Content-Range", `retailer 0-${allRecords.length}/${allRecords.length}`)
          res.set("X-Total-Count", allRecords.length)
          res.json(response);
        }
      });
});
```

Screenshot of the response:

[image]

getList from the data provider using axios:

```
getList: (resource, params) => {
    const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
    const { field, order } = params.sort;
    const query = {
        sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
        range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
        filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
    };
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

    return axios.get(url).then((response) => {

        console.log(response.headers) // Returns content length and type
        let records = response.data.map(record => ({ id: record.barcode, ...record }))
        return {
            data: records,
            total: records.length,
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a server side issue. In your react admin

1. Are you using a custom data provider?
2. If not is your response actually the data or is it like response.data ? If so you just make a custom data provider. I had the same issue.

Comment: Hey mate so I'm using a custom data provider(updated code) headers.get('content-range') is always empty

Comment: Ok actually what this is to do with express on AWS Lambda, I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: @MrkFldig your image above shows both content range and x-total-count set

Comment: Yeah actually they show in chrome but the httpClient doesn't get access it was actually the CORS was setup in express, I'll post an answer shortly! You are right though I first encountered this issue and then moved to a custom dataProvider :-)

Comment: @MrkFldig What was the solution? I'm facing the same issue, my API is built on Django Rest Framework, data is being returned but headers.get('content-Range') is returning null

Comment: Hey buddy, lemmy dig the code out, give me a few hours!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved mine if you have access to your API code.

1. npm install cors

then in your index file add as follows, make sure cors comes after express

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

// configs for cors and others
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

2. goto your routes

   ```
    const cors = require('cors');

        const corsOptions = {
          origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
          optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        };

        // PRE-FLIGHT
        router
          .route('/', cors(corsOptions))
        router
          .route('/:id', cors(corsOptions))
   ```

   3. in your controller

      res.set({
      'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Range',
      'Content-Range': `X-Total-Count: ${1} - ${rowCount} / ${rowCount}`
      });

   if you don't have access to your API, then use this.

   ```
    const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
      if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
      }
    // add your own headers here
       options.headers.set('X-Custom-Header', 'foobar');
      // const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       const token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
         options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
    };
   ```

   REF: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#usage